# Counter / Index in a pandas dataframe based on column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df
Date Application Weekday
02.01 A           3
02.01 B           3
03.01 A           4
03.01 B           4
04.01 A           5
04.01 B           5
05.01 A           6
05.01 B           6
```

And I want to filter out the weekdays: 5,6 and want to have a new index based on the dates, that means i would like to get:

```
df
Date Application Weekday Index
02.01 A           3        1
02.01 B           3        1 
03.01 A           4        2
03.01 B           4        2
```

How can i get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and create new column with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html), lambda function is necessary for processing filtered data:

```
df = df[df['Weekday'].lt(5)].assign(Index = lambda x: pd.factorize(x['Date'])[0] + 1)
print (df)
   Date Application  Weekday  Index
0  2.01           A        3      1
1  2.01           B        3      1
2  3.01           A        4      2
3  3.01           B        4      2
```

Comment: I get the error: `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`